# Bash script command to wait until docker-compose process has finished before moving on

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

We have a bash script that installs a program, which includes running a `docker-compose` file. One of the services, RabbitMQ, takes some time to load and I need a command to wait until it's loaded before the other services are loaded. We were using a `sleep` command, but our customers use different laptops, so it takes longer to load on some than others. Is there a way to just hold it until it finishes loading the service before moving on to the next without using the `sleep` command? I have included the part of the script below. Thanks!

```
# Execute applications
cd /opt/program
docker-compose up -d
echo "waiting for message queue..."
sleep 15

echo "starting ingest manager"

cd /opt/program/scripts
chmod +x start-manager.sh
./start-manager.sh &
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already stated in the other answers you'll have to do an application-specific readiness-check for your container. Personally I prefer to provide these checks/scripts with the container image, e.g. by adding the `wait-for-it.sh` (see [ErikMD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57530775/11932806)) or similar scripts to the image and executing them within the running container e.g. with `docker exec` (as proposed by [Ahmed Arafa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535541/11932806)).

This has some advantages over running the check on the host:

- you can provide all required scripts and dependencies with the container image
- you don't need to make any assumptions about the host (e.g. when testing via an api endpoint: is `wget`/`curl` available on the host, or even a `bash`/shell? Is the `docker`/`docker-compose` command executed on the same host as the docker deamon, i.e. could you reach the container via `localhost`?)
- you don't have to expose any ports/endpoints to the outside world only for checking container status
- you can provide different check scripts with different versions of the image without having to modify the start script

So, to apply this method to your example, simply add a script - e.g. `is_ready.sh` - to the image, execute it within the container with `docker-compose exec` and act upon its exit status:

```sh
# Execute applications
cd /opt/program
docker-compose up -d
echo "waiting for message queue..."

while ! docker-compose exec rabbitmq /is_ready.sh; do sleep 1; done

echo "starting ingest manager"

cd /opt/program/scripts
chmod +x start-manager.sh
./start-manager.sh &
```

where `is_ready.sh` may look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

rabbitmqctl status
```

---

Going even further down this road you may leverage the native healtcheck feature of [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck). With these `docker` will automatically execute the defined healthcheck script/command and indicate the current health in the container status.

Incorporated into your script this could look like:

```sh
# Execute applications
cd /opt/program
docker-compose up -d
echo "waiting for message queue..."

is_healthy() {
    service="$1"
    container_id="$(docker-compose ps -q "$service")"
    health_status="$(docker inspect -f "{{.State.Health.Status}}" "$container_id")"

    if [ "$health_status" = "healthy" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

while ! is_healthy rabbitmq; do sleep 1; done

echo "starting ingest manager"

cd /opt/program/scripts
chmod +x start-manager.sh
./start-manager.sh &
```

with the healthcheck defined in the `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
...
services:
  rabbitmq:
    ...
    healtcheck:
      test: rabbitmqctl status
```

For more complex healthchecks you can also add a longer script to the image and execute that instead.

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked, except for rabbitmqctl status, I used rabbitmqctl wait with a timeout and where rabbit is running to get the pid. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `docker-compose up -d` command is run in the background in "detached mode", but I guess that your setup exposes at least one web service…
If yes, you can rely on a tool such as [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to precisely wait for this service to be ready.

First, download and inspect this script:

https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/raw/master/wait-for-it.sh

Next, assuming your `docker-compose.yml` setup exposes a web service at `localhost:9090` with:

```
version: 3
services:
  frontend:
    image: user/image
    ports:
      - '9090:8080'
```

You could refactor your Bash script (named e.g. `run.sh`) as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# retrieve and remember the directory where is stored this script
srcdir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )
# we assume the script "wait-for-it.sh" is also in this directory

# Execute applications
cd /opt/program
docker-compose up -d

# Change the working directory now
cd /opt/program/scripts
chmod +x start-manager.sh

echo "waiting for message queue..."
"$srcdir/wait-for-it.sh" -h localhost -p 9090 -s -t 0 -- ./start-manager.sh
```

For more details, some online doc. is available at https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it#readme

Answer (score 1):

First you need to determine specific name for rabbitmq container in your docker-compose.yaml by adding:

```
version: "3"

services:
        web:
                image: rabbitmq:latest
                container_name: rabbitmq
```

to service block

And script will be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/program
docker-compose up -d
echo "waiting for message queue..."

rabbitmq_status() { 
        docker exec -it rabbitmq rabbitmqctl status
}

rabbitmq_status

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "starting ingest manager"
        cd /opt/program/scripts
        chmod +x start-manager.sh
        ./start-manager.sh &
else
        echo "rabbitmq container is not running"
fi
```

Which will not move to the next step till rabbitmq container is up and running.

Comment: using `docker-compose exec $service` instead of `docker exec` you don't need to rely on a static container to be set in the `docker-compose.yml`